# How to undo a property change in the Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, merge

Let's say that I **changed** the `svn:ignore` property for `^/trunk/doc` and added a new file `^/trunk/newfile` in r100. Now I would like to undo the change to the `svn:ignore` property in `^/trunk/doc` but leave `newfile` unchanged.

What is the correct way to do this **in svn 1.7**?

I've tried

```
svn merge -c -100 ^/trunk/doc
```

but it seems that reverse merging will only record file/directory changes but not property changes.

Comment: What version of Subversion do you use? I just did a quick test and was able to reverse-merge the property changes as expected. I'm on 1.8.

Comment: Svn 1.7 - and I can't go higher, at least not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties on files are not versioned, something like svn:ignore or mime-type will apply to the file/directory as a flag on the repository, not on a per-revision basis. Some properties like author and date, are versioned.

So, the ones that are unversioned are simply set or deleted. The other ones have to be committed as part of a checkin. If you're trying to revert a non-revision property, then you're out of luck, the old contents are not stored anywhere. If you want to revert a revprop, just revert the revision.

Answer (score 0):

`svn propdel svn:ignore ^/trunk/doc` and commit new revision

Comment: I've updated my question and worded it more carefully... It is not about deleting the property, but about reverting the contents.